# How to groupby Date by Months and countries in the data set, SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

`covid_data = covid_data.groupby(by=['location'] ,pd.Grouper(freq='MS', key='date'))`

> I have run this code but, I cannot group months in the date and location.

Comment: Use `covid_data = covid_data.groupby(by=['location' ,pd.Grouper(freq='MS', key='date')])`

Comment: replace value `]` in your code

Comment: Thank you very much, dude. lots of Respect.